# Copying generic .db files to sdcard

Tags: android

How can I copy a generic .db file (not part of my resources, like contacts.db) from the device filesystem to another location say sdcard?
Can I use -

InputStream ins = getResources().openRawResource("path to my .db file");

And then proceed as you showed above.

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: You cant copy database used either by the Android system or native apps without having root access. Plus you would also need a root explorer.

Comment: Why would you want to do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can't copy "generic" db files anywhere, you can't even access them. They are private to the application that created the database and uses them.

See the [Security and Permissions](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/security/security.html#userid) documentation for more info.

Of course, any .db files that you do have access to, those for your own apps, you can copy simply as files (though you'll want to make sure to close connections before doing so).

Applications like Contacts expose their data via a [ContentProvider](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers.html), but they do not allow you to access the db file directly (for obvious reasons).

Comment: Thanks Charlie I would understand that editing the contacts.db file will not be allowed but can't we even copy it and send it over to a server or to sdcard like a normal file (since we know its location). Cant we set read permissions in the manifest.xml to achieve this? I am trying to write a backup application and using the contacts api to read all the fields is very time consuming.